# How to choose training data to find many small instances of an object on a bigger image - Mask RCNN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

Let's say I have such task: finding all windows that are on the image. Can I just use for training many images of a single window to then find many windows on one image (image depicts block of flats)? If Yes, How should I choose the size of each training image? What can be the size of my validation image?

Comment: Are you allowed to use YoloV3? Anchor boxes is useful to detect overlapping object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can. But the problem here is that you will expect your algorithm to find one window in the image. You can solve this by cropping the test image (block of flats) to smaller parts and trying to predict window in every one of those cropped images. That said, you'll have to preprocess your images of a single window in many ways - blur them, change the sizes, rotate (skew) them, input some artificial noise... But it definitely won't be perfect. I suggest you use YOLOv2 or Yolov3 or some other object detection algorithms and models and train them on images of flats with lots of windows.

Comment: Have not tried Thanks for asnwer. I have not tried Yolo v3 - I will give it try.
But I was more looking into instance segmentation rather than just object detection and putting bounding box around(In fact I do not know how does bounding box exactly is choosen).  In case of rectangular windows, probably bounding box ~= segmentation. 
Do You think, for the sake of accuarcy, If I create a training images fullfilled with windows (artificially processed) with a size of testing image depicting block of flats, would Mask R-CNN work?